# How to add snakeyaml dependency to sbt-liquibase plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, liquibase

This is a simple scala project. I have added `sbt-liquibase` to plugins.sbt. My changelog for liquibase is in yaml format. According to https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/yaml-format.html, the `snakeyaml` should be used for changelog in yaml format. Since, I sbt-liquibase plugin, I could not find where should the dependency be declared for sbt-liquibase plugin.

```scala
//plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.permutive" % "sbt-liquibase" % "1.2.0")
```

build.sbt is

```scala
//build.sbt
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name                        := "diy-quill",
    libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
      sqlite,

    ),
    liquibaseChangelog          := java.nio.file.Path.of("src/main/resources/db/changelog.yaml").toFile(),
    liquibaseDriver             := "org.sqlite.JDBC",
    liquibaseUrl                := "jdbc:sqlite:./target/shopkart.db",
    liquibaseUsername           := "",
    liquibasePassword           := ""
  )
  .enablePlugins(ScalafmtPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(SbtLiquibase)
```

Since `sbt-liquibase` could not find yaml parser, I get the following error on executing the task `liquibaseUpdate`.

```bash
sbt:hello-world> liquibaseUpdate
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last liquibaseUpdate for the full output
[error] (liquibaseUpdate) liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException: Cannot find parser that supports /home/dx/dev/play/scala-projects/diy-quill/src/main/resources/db/changelog.yaml
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 2, 2023, 4:24:04 PM
```

Where and how should the dependency for sbt-liquibase plugin be declared?

Application does not require snakeyaml.

However, when the liquibase changelog is represented in xml format, no additional dependencies are required, no such errors occur.

Found a stackoverflow reference [Sbt Plugin Add Dependency to project/build.sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972955/sbt-plugin-add-dependency-to-project-build-sbt) which recommends to use `compilerPlugin`. Even that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `snakeyaml` to plugins.sbt solves the issue. This is project/plugins.sbt looks like to use changelog for sbt-liquibase in yaml format.

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.permutive" % "sbt-liquibase" % "1.2.0")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.yaml" % "snakeyaml" % "1.33"
)
```